# Greek letters are replaced with ??? once I convert a docx into pdf using PHPWord?

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf, laravel-5.7, phpword

I made the following simple laravel artisan command:

```
Artisan::command('test:pdf',function(){

    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF);
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath('.');

    $tmpFile = storage_path().'/contracts/test.docx';
    $outfile = storage_path().'/contracts/test.pdf';

    $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($tmpFile);
    $phpWord->save($outfile,'PDF');

});
```

It receives a docx file and converts it into pdf. But for an ackward reason the docx contains greek letters and once rendered in pdf are converted into `????`.

So any ideas how I can save a pdf file from a docx respecting UTF-8 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by DOMPDF's constraints that is unable to render the font for Greek Language.

You can either replace all fonts to DejaVu ones OR use mpdf.

```
Artisan::command('test:pdf',function(){

    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF);
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath('.');

    $tmpFile = storage_path().'/contracts/test.docx';
    $outfile = storage_path().'/contracts/test.pdf';

    $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($tmpFile);
    $phpWord->save($outfile,'PDF');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching on the internet, I finally found the right solution for Persian letters and converted my .docx file to pdf.

To convert word files (.docx) to Pdf , you must follow these steps:

1. convert word file to html with [this library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)
2. convert html file to pdf with [this library](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/examples/example_002.php)

With this method, I was able to convert the word file to pdf without any problem in Persian letters.

Comment: Maybe conversion to HTML adds extra layer that may not render properly the html due to limitation upon css styling at html->pdf convertion

Comment: But now this method has worked for me and I was able to add different types of fonts to it and it creates Persian words and PDF files without any problems.